# Debian 9.5 ошибка autoremove

Tags: linux, debian, gnome

Установил себе несколько дней назад последнюю версию Debian и столкнулся со следующей проблемой. `autoremove` выдает ошибку:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cups-bsd : Depends: libcups2 (= 2.2.8-5) but 2.2.1-8+deb9u1 is installed
            Depends: cups-client (= 2.2.8-5) but 2.2.1-8+deb9u1 is installed
            Depends: cups-common (>= 2.2.8-5) but 2.2.1-8+deb9u1 is installed
 libpulsedsp : Depends: libpulse0 (= 10.0-1+deb9u1) but 11.1-5 is installed
 pulseaudio-utils : Depends: libpulse0 (= 10.0-1+deb9u1) but 11.1-5 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

После этого логичным было бы попытаться сделать `apt --fix-broken install`, но и он завершается с ошибкой.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libdw1 tix
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  cups-bsd libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulse0 pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
Suggested packages:
  pavumeter pavucontrol paman paprefs
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  cups-bsd libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulse0 pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 5 downgraded, 0 to remove and 945 not upgraded.
114 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,531 kB of archives.
After this operation, 268 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: warning: downgrading cups-bsd from 2.2.8-5 to 2.2.1-8+deb9u1
(Reading database ... 128255 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../cups-bsd_2.2.1-8+deb9u1_amd64.deb ...
update-inetd: cannot open /etc/inetd.conf: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/cups-bsd_2.2.1-8+deb9u1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 installed cups-bsd package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/cups-bsd_2.2.1-8+deb9u1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Мне кажется это связанно с тем что у меня проблемы с Bluetooth и я немогу установить Gnome-Tweak-Tools.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Возможно, это связано с наличием нескольких версий в sources.list, и вам поможет явное указание через `-t` какой-нибудь из них.

А может быть, простой `touch /etc/inetd.conf` перед выполнением `apt-get -f install` способен решить ситуацию.

Comment: Помогло, закомментировал ресурсы, потом создал файл и ввел последнюю команду. Все ок.